# How to get "p value" for time series data to detect significant change

Tags: spatial-statistics, ndvi, change-detection

I have yearly maximum NDVI data (1982-2008) and extracted all value to Excel. Also calculated slope value for each point during the 27 years. All of you know the slope value represents changes per unit (per year). Now I would like to look for significant changes in NDVI over the 27 years. So I have to get "p value" for each point. How I calculate it?

I tried it in Excel. Firstly I have to estimate t-test, but i don't know which value should be in place of  'mu' for this case! After estimating it I can find p value using TDIST function in MS excel.

Comment: Could you give us some more information? What is your overall _aim_ in examining NDVI? Are you really interested in 'significant change' for individual points, or in describing changes over a larger area, perhaps?

Comment: Could you use a program like SPSS instead of excel? Usually it's better for statistical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Excel, but it's possible in R with whole rasters...if you have bi-monthly NDVI rasters, the code would be the following for getting trends significant at the 95% level (I've written a blog about it here: [Trend analysis](http://matinbrandt.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/pixel-wise-time-series-trend-anaylsis-with-ndvi-gimms-and-r/).

```
  # load all Geotiffs from the GIMMS folder:
    library(raster)
    setwd("~/GIMMS")
    sg = stack(list.files(pattern='*.tif'))
        gimms = brick(sg)
        rm(sg)


 #aggregate to annual sums:

        fun <- function(x) { 
         gimms.ts = ts(x, start=c(1982,1), end=c(2008,24), frequency=24)
         x <- aggregate(gimms.ts) 
         }
    gimms.sum <- calc(gimms, fun)
    gimms.sum=gimms.sum/12
    plot(gimms.sum)

# extract the slope raster

    time <- 1:nlayers(gimms.sum) 
    fun=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m = lm(x ~ time); summary(m)$coefficients[2] }}
    gimms.slope=calc(gimms.sum, fun)
    gimms.slope=gimms.slope*27
    plot(gimms.slope)

# mask all values which are not significant at the 95% level:

    fun=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m = lm(x ~ time); summary(m)$coefficients[8] }}
    p <- calc(gimms.sum, fun=fun)
    plot(p, main="p-Value")

        m = c(0, 0.05, 1, 0.05, 1, 0)
        rclmat = matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
        p.mask = reclassify(p, rclmat)
        fun=function(x) { x[x<1] <- NA; return(x)}
        p.mask.NA = calc(p.mask, fun)

    trend.sig = mask(gimms.slope, p.mask.NA)
    plot(trend.sig, main="significant NDVI change")
```